# How to select max value of each group when this value is stored in timestamp type column?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following table in my database.

```
CREATE TABLE `market_messages` (
  `pm_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `pm_item_index` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pm_item_id` varchar(11) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `pm_item_sender` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `pm_item_client` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci NOT NULL,
  `pm_item_sender_id` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `pm_item_client_id` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `pm_item_name` varchar(80) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `pm_sender` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `pm_receiver` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `pm_entry_start` timestamp NULL DEFAULT NULL,
  `pm_message` text COLLATE utf8_polish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `pm_index` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `pm_type` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `pm_user_offer` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci DEFAULT NULL,
  `pm_status` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_polish_ci DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=MyISAM DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_polish_ci;
```

Now I'm trying to group messages and order in specific sequence on the list.
I need to list comments based on last entry into `m_entry_start` column which type is timestamp.

Here is my query, but result is not good:

```
$sql = "SELECT * 
        FROM market_messages 
        WHERE (pm_item_client = '$user_name' 
                AND pm_item_client_id = '$user_id') 
        OR      (pm_item_sender = '$user_name' 
                AND pm_item_sender_id = '$user_id') 
        GROUP BY pm_item_id, pm_item_client_id, pm_item_sender_id 
        ORDER BY MAX(pm_entry_start) DESC;";
```

Result is not this what I have expected.
`Echo $fetch['m_entry_start'];` doesn't give me right result.

I'm expecting max value of `pm_entry_start` timestamp from each group, but in results is taken probably first value. Additionally `pm_entry_start' is echoed with ago() function to show elapsed time. Ago function is converting timestamp in format 2021-10-01 10:00:19 to something like 3 minutes ago, or 1 day ago etc.
This is example result:

| $user_name | ago(timestamp) |
| --- | --- |
| Adam | 1 month ago |
| Eve | 23 days ago |
| Terese | 2 months ago |
| Mark | 5 days ago |
| Monica | 3 min ago |

I expecting results in order based on timestamp in descending order so from the last entry to the first.

| $user_name | ago(timestamp) |
| --- | --- |
| Monica | 3 min ago |
| Mark | 5 days ago |
| Eve | 23 days ago |
| Adam | 1 month ago |
| Terese | 2 months ago |

How to write the good query? I have started programming in PHP last year. This project is my first with use of MySQL database. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Did you try using `MAX()`

Comment: if you have started you should look at [how to prevent sql injection in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/how-can-i-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

Comment: Yes, I have tried to use SELECT MAX(pm_entry_start), ... FROM ... but this query don't give any result to display. I have read somewhere on Stack pages that MAX() is working only with INT type of data. Still don't know how to fetch max value of timestamp.

Comment: @SylwesterBogusiak please edit your question and add  some data examples and your expected result

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html has some hints on how to do stuff like this.

Comment: @ErgestBasha I have edited my question. Hopefully this help to solve my problem.

Comment: @CBroe OK. I will try to use this examples. Thanks.

Comment: @ErgestBasha ago(timestamp) function just print result from MySQL query and has no impact to sort result. When I use echo $fetch['m_entry_start'] instead of echo ago($fetch['m_entry_start']) this give the same order in result just time is printed in other form. I need to change MySQL query, and I hope this is possible to select MAX(timestamp) from group of messages.

Comment: @ErgestBasha You don't understand. Time in MySQL query is fetched in TIMESTAMP format not VARCHAR from table market_messages. Ago function has no impact to sort results, only can display Time it in other format. Forget about ago function and just in simplicity once echo $fetch['m_entry_start'] for each group.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found the solution:
`SELECT ..., MAX(pm_entry_start) AS pm_entry_start FROM ...` was missing part of MySQL query.
Before I have tried only:
`SELECT ..., MAX(pm_entry_start) FROM ...`